# How to add calendar event in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

What is the best way to add a calendar event in React native? Is there an api out of the box or I need to use a third party npm packages.

I have looked into the api docs of react-native on following link but could not find anything about calendar.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibilityinfo

Comment: I suggest you to use https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

Comment: Use this package https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars